# Missing special characters in Leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to display the proper name of cities with special characters in spanish such as 'tilde' Á, however I'm getting false encoding in the popup layers as you can see in the image:

[image: leaflet popup wrong encoding UTF-8]
I have my html charset defined as `<meta charset="utf-8" />` and the .geojson is also alright:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{
"type":"Point","coordinates":[-74.1059716,4.650528403]},
"properties":{
"DPTO_CCDGO":11.000000,
"MPIO_CCDGO":1.000000,
"CPOB_CNMBR":"BOGOTÁ D.C.",
"CPOB_NANO":2011.000000,
(...)
```

Any idea on how to fix it? 
I already checked with Chrome 58 and Firefox 53 with same result.

Comment: Is it possible to create a running sample where we can reproduce the same issue...jsfiddle or stackoverflow editor?

Comment: Are you sure the issue comes from the encoding ? Or maybe the font you are using doesn't have special characters ?

Comment: After upload the example at bl.ocks, characters appear correctly. Maybe it is a matter of my machine codification.

Comment: @SoufianeLasri  Thanks for your answer. Effectively saving the text file with UTF-8 format solved the issue.